# Added fields don't show up at a content creation form

Tags: 7, entities

I tried adding location type of field to gather reviewed place's location. I did everything properly and it didn't show up at a creation form, when trying to submit it said I was missing my location info but I couldn't see where to fill them. I checked everything * Things that I tried to do:

- Re-creating field
- Adding simple text field
- Flushing all cache
- Deleting my custom style for creation form
- Checking Developer tools with F12 to see if there is a div element for these entries

I am not sure what else should I try. Maybe someone can put me on a track?

Comment: what module are you using for the location field?

Comment: Location module